# Teams History - Properties Edited doesn't show which property was edited

Tags: feature-request, old-teams

When I update a property (such as the twitter account) of a Team, I can see the edit in the Teams History, but I can't actually see *which* property was edited.

[image]

<sup>(*I modified some of DOM text before taking the screenshot*)</sup>

I can guess well enough based on the value of the edit, but it'd be nice to know for sure which property was changed.